# PL/SQL API to list down Invalid package calls inside ORACLE APEX pages

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-19.1

I am looking for a PL/SQL API to list down any Invalid package calls inside APEX Pages.

I am aware of Advisor functionality Under Utilities for every application, but having a PL/SQL api would help us incorporate these checks into our build processes.

Any leads into this is highly appreciated :-)

Comment: This might be suitable as an enhancement request https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=55447

Comment: @JeffreyKemp. Thanks for the link. I raised a feature request for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Raised a feature request for the same.

https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=55447:19:15237329419453:::19:P19_ID:197372154536345300754964317521429928331